# I am writing a simple face recognition program I faced Syntax Error

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, face-recognition

I have created the code for Face recognition :

```py
import numpy as np
import argparse
import cv2

ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-i", "--image" ,required=True , help="path to input image")
ap.add_argument("-p", "--prototxt" , required=True, help="path to Caffe 'deploy' prototxt file")
ap.add_argument("-m", "--model" , required=True , help="path to Caffe pre-trained model")
ap.add_argument("-c", "--confidence" , type=float , default=0.5 , help="minimum probability to filter weak detections")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

print("[INFO] loading model...")
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromCaffe(args["prototxt"],args["model"])

image = cv2.imread(args["image"])
(h,w) = image.shape[:2]
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image,(300,300),1.0,(300,300),(104.0, 177.0, 123.0))

print("[INFO] computing object detections...")

net.setInput(blob)
detections = net.forward()

for i in range(0,detections.shape[2]):
   confidence = detections[0,0,i,2]
   if confidence > args["confidence"]:
       box = detections[0, 0, i, 3:7] * np.array([w, h, w, h]) \
       (startX, startY, endX, endY) = box.astype("int")
       text = "{:.2f}%".format(confidence * 100)
   y = startY - 10 if startY - 10 > 10 else startY + 10
   cv2.rectangle(image, (startX, startY), (endX, endY), (0, 0, 255), 2)
   cv2.putText(image, text, (startX, y),
               cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.45, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv2.imshow("Output", image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

While running the program, I face `SyntaxError`:

> File "tensorflowexperiment", line 19
>
> print("[INFO] computing object detections...")
>
> ^ SyntaxError: invalid syntax

The first `print` command doesn't give any error.

Why there is error with the second `print` command?

Comment: `blob=cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image,(300,300),1.0,(300,300),(104.0, 177.0, 123.0))` misses a closing parenthesis at the end of the line

Comment: Just a hint for the future: When you get an error message, try to read it. :) Did you stare at line 19 for 5 minutes and did not see the missing parenthesis? That happens sometimes. In that case, try to simplify the line where a `SyntaxError` is indicated until the Error disappears.

Comment: @forrealism Did it help you to add parenthesis at line19? If yes please accept the answer

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach  you are right . It was my bad time. Sorry.

Comment: No need to say sorry. :) Your post motivated me to formulate (and answer) the more general question how to deal with Syntax Errors in Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58774794/how-to-tackle-syntaxerror-in-python/58774795#58774795

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`blob=cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(cv2.resize(image,(300,300),1.0,(300,300),(104.0, 177.0, 123.0))` here is one closing bracket missing